# Concatenate Date and Time

Tags: t-sql

I m trying to concatenate `Date` and `Time` using the below line but i m getting an error. Any help?

`Time` column type: `Time (0)`

`CONVERT(date, getdate()) + ' ' + CONVERT(time(0), [Time]) AS Date_Time`

> The data types date and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: Use `CONCAT`. It converts implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do that - one of them is to convert both parts to `DateTime` which supports the add (`+`) operator:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(GetDate() As Date) As DateTime) + (CAST([Time] As DateTime) As Date_Time
```

The casting of `GetDate()` to `Date` and back to `DateTime` resets the time portion to midnight.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below and it is working:

`CAST(CONVERT(date, getdate()) AS nvarchar) + ' ' + CAST(CONVERT(time(0), [Time]) AS nvarchar) AS Date_Time`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you are trying to convert `' '` to a data type compatible with `date` and `time`, hence the error.

The next problem is that a `date` does not have a `time` component, hence to combine the two you need to use a `datetime` or similar data type.

```
declare @Time as Time = '12:30:00';

select @Time as Time,
  -- Get today's date as a   date .
  Cast( GetDate() as Date ) as Today,
  -- Get today's date and convert it to a   datetime   so that the time can be added.
  Cast( Cast( GetDate() as Date ) as DateTime ) + Cast( @Time as DateTime ) as DateAndTime;
```

Note that `time` values need to be converted to `datetime` (or another compatible type) before adding the values. Curiously, SQL Server 2008 didn't require that step.

Comment: Running this script throws the following error: "The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator.". You must convert the time to datetime too.

Comment: @ZoharPeled When I tested the code on my ancient notebook with SS2008 it worked correctly, SQLfiddle with SS2017 kicked out the error that you observed. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing out the error.